# C# thread doesn't stop

Tags: c#, multithreading

updater.SearchByFunctionName returns after 5-10 seconds, I want to increase the progress bar's value while it's working, but it never stops.

I'm new to threading, so maybe it's something very basic, I don't know.

```
           Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                updater.SearchByFunctionName(testsuiteBox.SelectedValue.ToString(), functionNameBox.Text);
            });

            t.Start();

            progressBar.Value = 0;


            while(t.IsAlive)
            {

                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                if (progressBar.Value >= 200 )

                    {

                        progressBar.Value = 0;
                    }

                    progressBar.Value += 20;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're blocking the UI thread, and that is preventing any updates to the progressbar.

You should use a `Timer`, attach an event to the `Tick` event and place the code to update the progress bar in there.

It also seems that you're manually making a Marquee style progress bar.  `ProgressBar` has support for this built in.  You can just add:

```
myProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```

and you can set the `MarqueeAnimationSpeed` to what is appropriate.  After that you don't need to do anything for it.